# Powershell Set variable from function result

Tags: powershell

I am not sure what the heck I am doing wrong here but the code below return the following error message:

The term 'identityTest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Here is my sample/test code:

```
#Bunch of Global vars
$UrlToUse = identityTest

function identityTest
{
    $internalMatch = ".*inbound"
    $externalMatch = ".*outbound"
    $fqdn = "blahblah_inbound"

    if ( $fqdn -match $internalMatch )
    {
        return "http://in3"
        Write-Host "Inbound Hit"
    }
    if ( $fqdn -match $externalMatch )
    {
        return "http://out"
        Write-Host "Outbond Hit"
    }
    else
    {
        return "http://default"
        write-host "Default Hit"
    }
}    


function sampleTest
{
    write-host "will upload to the following URL: + $UrlToUse
}

Write-Host $UrlToUse
```

Not sure if I am taking the correct approach here but this is what I am trying to accomplish.  I plan to set UrlToUse as a global variable depending on the result of the if statements in the indetityTest function which will determine and return the correct one.  From there I will use the same global var throughout the rest of my code.  An example that i created would using the same var $UrlToUse within another function, in this case name sampleTest.

I don't understand why this is not working.  I come from a Perl background and might be confusing how things work in powershell. Any tips pointer etc would be really really appreciated.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Script files are read from top to bottom. Every object/script/function/etc. you reference have to be initialized earlier in the session or in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the function identityTest before it is called. Like this:

```
function identityTest
{
    $internalMatch = ".*inbound"
    $externalMatch = ".*outbound"
    $fqdn = "blahblah_inbound"

    if ( $fqdn -match $internalMatch )
    {
        return "http://in3"
        Write-Host "Inbound Hit"
    }
    if ( $fqdn -match $externalMatch )
    {
        return "http://out"
        Write-Host "Outbond Hit"
    }
    else
    {
        return "http://default"
        write-host "Default Hit"
    }
}    

#Bunch of Global vars
$UrlToUse = identityTest



function sampleTest
{
    write-host "will upload to the following URL: + $UrlToUse"
}

Write-Host $UrlToUse
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Didn't realize that the function order mattered.